# Adding new list in Listview Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, listview, kendo-ui

I would like to make a list view with a adding new record button in jquery, like in kendo ui

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html

As you can see when you click the add new record button the new list is created and set as first list. What I want to do is to put it at the bottom of the list (to be last) . How can I do that?

Comment: It adds the new element as the first of the current page. What do you want to do if you are not in the last page? Or do you want to go to the last page plus insert it at the bottom?

Comment: I want to insert it (the new element )at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a `ListView` defined as:

```
var listView = $("#listView").kendoListView({
    dataSource  : dataSource,
    template    : kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    editTemplate: kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html())
}).data("kendoListView");
```

And the following HTML:

        
            
                
                Add new record

Define a `button` for adding as:

```
$(".k-add-button").click(function (e) {
    var total = dataSource.data().length;
    dataSource.insert(total, {});
    dataSource.page(dataSource.totalPages());
    listView.edit(listView.element.children().last());
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

What this does is:

1. Get number of elements in the `ListView` `DataSource` using `data().length`.
2. Then `insert` an element in that position (since this is base 0, I don't need to add 1).
3. Go to that last page of the `DataSource` using `dataSource.page(dataSource.totalPages())`.
4. And finally `edit` the `last` element of the current page of the `ListView`.

Comment: @onabai how can we add multiple new element at bottom?.

Comment: @BharatChodvadiya Did you try repeating `dataSource.insert(total, {});`? How many do you want to append?

Comment: You can just use `dataSource.add()` instead of inserting at the end.

Comment: It should be listView.content.children().last() not listView.element.children().last().